# Sharkovskii's theorem in two dimensions?

Tags: reference-request, dynamical-systems, systems-of-equations

> **Question**
>
> A weak form of Sharkovskii's theorem in $1$D dynamical systems states that, if a continuous function $f:I\to I$ does not include a periodic point of least period $2$ on $I$, then there is no periodic point of least period $3$ on $I$. (This can be strengthened to the conclusion that every periodic point on $I$ is a fixed point.)
>
> Are there generalizations of this result to dynamical systems in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

**Motivation**

One of my first [answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/864503/137524) addressed a seemingly-simple algebra problem: Given a particular function $f(x)$, are there distinct real $x,y,z$ which solve the system of equations

$$y=f(x),\quad z=f(y),\quad x=f(z)\quad?$$

This amounts to finding real $x$ such that $x=f^{3}(x)$ but $x\neq f(x)\neq f^2(x)$ (in the sense of function composition); in other words, $x$ is a periodic point of least period $3$. The advantage of this formulation is that we can apply Sharkovskii's theorem to deduce the following criterion: If $f(x)$ has no real periodic point of least period $2$, then neither does it have a real periodic point of least period $3$.

Thus a necessary condition for non-trivial solutions of the system of equations above is that a non-trivial solution exist for the system $x=f(y),\quad y=f(x)$.  In fact, Sharkovskii's theorem furthermore implies that the same is true for *every* such multiplet of equations. This means that, by ruling out real primitive $2$-cycles, we have the possibility to immediately rule out the solution of all such systems of equations. That is rather powerful...

What I wonder is whether this approach is applicable to a variant of such systems. Suppose we instead consider a continuous map $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$ and the system of equations $$z=f(x,y),\quad x=f(y,z),\quad y=f(z,x).$$ We may express this in terms of periodic points via the map $F(x,y)=(f(x,y),y)$, for then the above system is equivalent to $$(z,y)=F(x,y),\quad (y,x)=F(z,x),\quad (x,z)=F(y,z).$$ Thus a solution with distinct real $x,y,z$ would be a periodic point of least period $f$ for the $2$D mapping $f(x,y)$.

Alas, Sharkovskii's theorem applies only to continuous $1$D mappings. So, unlike the first case, there is no obvious necessary condition for the existence of a $3$-cycle. To overcome this would require some version of Sharkovskii's theorem to hold in two dimensions. So some bridging of my ignorance would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure if this addresses your question or not, but, given $n$, it's easy to construct a map of ${\mathbb R}^2$ with a single fixed point and periodic points of only period $n$.  Just use a rotation through the angle $2\pi/n$.

Comment: @MarkMcClure: Well, it definitely indicates that the obvious generalization fails. But I'm open to results require restrictions upon $f$, or give a different criterion on periodic points, or some other useful direction of which I'm ignorant.

Comment: "Chaos in Discrete Dynamical Systems: A Visual Introduction in 2 Dimensions" by Ralph Abraham
also google (images ) Gumowski and Mira for some interesting two dimensional maps.

Comment: @Semiclassical i'm being daft here but I'm struggling to understand why a periodic point of at least period 2 doesn't already (trivially) include the case of a periodic point of at least period 3, since 3 is at least 2. Please help!

Comment: @RobertFrost a point of least period 2 is not a point of period 3. For instance, the map $f(x)=-x)$ has $f(f(x))=x$ and $f(f(f(x)))=-x$, so every nonzero number has period 2 but is neither a fixed point nor a period 3 point. (However, every such point is also 4,6,8,...-periodic. So it does make sense to specify that these are all points of least period 2.)

Comment: @Semiclassical oh ok so when you say a point of at least period $n$, you mean effectively cyclic of order exactly $n$ so the trivial loop $1-4-2-1$ of the Collatz conjecture is cyclic of order $3$ and you're calling each of its elements as "periodic of at least period 3"?